# unserialize error from a column in database

Tags: laravel

Since one day i have an exception to my view when i want to access to an unserialized column. it's really strange because in some pages it's working and some others i get an error

Hope someone could help me .. i don't know why sometimes it work and sometimes not. I also tested base64_encode() and base64_decode() but i get now an error to all my views from my different records

> unserialize error offet

Here my controller when i create the a new Order

```
     $order = new Order();
     $order->cart = serialize($cart);
     ...
     $order->save();
```

Now my controller when i unserialize

```
public function show($id)
  {
      $order = Order::findOrFail($id);
      $order->cart = unserialize($order->cart);
      $order->cart->totalPrice;
      $prix_total = $order->cart->totalPrice;
      $structure_id = $order->structure_id;
      $structure = Structure::where('id' , '=' , $structure_id)->first();
      $federation = Structure::where('id' , '1')->first();

      return view('cotisation_structure/show' , compact('prix_total', 'order' , 'structure' , 'federation'));

  }
```

Now my view i display the records in my "cart" column :

```
@foreach($order->cart->items as $item)
                       <tr>
                           @if(Auth::user()->isFederation())
                               <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="{{$item['item']->id}}"></td>
                           @endif
                           <td><a href="{!! route('licencie.show', $item['item']->id) !!}">{{$item['item']->num_licence}}</a></td>
                           <th>{{$item['item']->lb_nom}}</th>
                           <th>{{$item['item']->lb_prenom}}</th>
                           <th>{{$item['item']->structure->nom_structure}}</th>
                               <td>
                                   @if($item['item']->lb_tricolore != null)
                                       {{$item['item']->lb_activite_tricolore}} - {{$item['item']->lb_tricolore}}
                                   @else
                                       {{$item['item']->activite_licencie->lb_activite}}
                                   @endif
                               </td>
                           <th>{{$item['item']->saison->lb_saison}}</th>
                           <th>{{$order->payment_method}}</th>
                           <th>{{$item['price']}} € </th>
                           <td>{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($order->date_achat)->format('d/m/Y')}}</td>
                       </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you are storing serialized field in `string` type of database table field and it gets stripped at 255 characters.

For further debugging I recommend to save the serialized data to log and when restoring then also. In this case you can compare if data that you saved is the same that was taken out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! i use "text" for the column . there is a limitation length for this type of field ?

Comment: should i use longtext ?

Comment: Depends on your serialized data size.
TEXT 65,535 (216−1) bytes = 64 KiB
MEDIUMTEXT 16,777,215 (224−1) bytes = 16 MiB
LONGTEXT 4,294,967,295 (232−1) bytes =  4 GiB

Comment: i changed to LONGTEXT to be sure. now i have no more exception for the moment. it's seems to work. thanks a lot for your help sir !!!!